# Regexp matching strings with maximum one character

Tags: java, regex, string, grep

I have files with multiple lines and a certain character that may only occur once (in the whole file); I need a way to check for which files that holds.

Let's say I have

```
1. 00000
2. 00050
3. 05500
4. 00000
```

Five can only occur once. How do I flag this file as malformed using bash and **grep**?

I suppose you would first check which lines contain a 5. If there's more than one line, stop. Then see if there's more than one five on that line, if so, stop. Is there a better way to do this?

Right now I would count the lines via

```
grep "5" file | wc -l.
```

If there's more than one, stop. If not, proceed with that one line. How do I then count how many 5's are there? At first I used 5{1} but that doesn't seem to work -- if the string is "55" it just matches every 5 in there, whereas I need maximum 1 five. Then I figured I'd see whether there's more than one 5 and if so, stop. But 5{2,} only works when there's multiple 5's after each other. On the other hand,

```
.*5.*5.*
```

matches only words with 2 or more 5's, but it seems so grotesque...

Any better suggestions? I'm sure there is but it's evening and this is as far as my brain goes for today, sorry. Remember, I can only use grep.

Comment: how about: `^[^5]*5[^5]*$`

Comment: Why can you only use grep - is this homework?

Answer (score 3):

To ensure string contains just one occurrence of `5`, use regex pattern

```
^[^5]*5[^5]*$
```

If one or no occurrence of `5` is required, use regex pattern

```
^[^5]*5?[^5]*$
```

If you want to match those strings that contains more than one occurrence of `5`, use regex pattern

```
5.*5
```

Comment: Thank you! 1 and 3 work perfectly but I can't get 2 to work, even when I use -p. I currently do `grep -P "^[^3]*3\?[^3]*$" file` but that doesn't seem to work. Not escaping ? doesn't either. Using Cygwin, might that be the problem?

Comment: @jns - With `-P` don't escape question mark! Use `grep -P "^[^3]*3?[^3]*$" file`

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
grep -o 5 file | wc -w
```

**Explanation:**
`grep -o` - outputs only "matches" (in out case, the "5"'s)
`wc -w` - counts "words" (tokens)

Comment: That -o flag... I did RTFM but somehow missed that. Now I feel silly :( but thank you.